# How to create a polygon using fields in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I don't have PostGIS, hence I use built-in functions.
I have got below query working correctly.
However, I need to find these values from the table

```
select area(circle( (polygon '(43.5042,-96.8391),(33.508,-112.1254),(33.4912,-111.9237),(33.4912,-111.9237),(33.4912,-111.9237),(38,-97)' ) ))
```

Below queries return error.
Any help on how to have the polygon from fields from a table?

```
select id, polygon '('||array_to_string(array_agg('('||latdec_src||','||longdec_src||')'),',') ||')'  from access where id='99999' and time >= '2017-01-03' and time < '2017-01-04' group by 1

select id, polygon array_agg('('||latdec_src||','||longdec_src||')')  from access where id='99999' and time >= '2017-01-03' and time < '2017-01-04' group by 1


select id, polygon array_agg(point(latdec_src,longdec_src))  from acesss where id='99999' and time >= '2017-01-03' and time < '2017-01-04' group by 1
```

Comment: And the error is...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something similar to:

```
WITH points (lat, lng, sort_order) AS
(
    VALUES 
       (43.5042, -96.8391, 1),
       (33.508, -112.1254, 2),
       (33.4912,-111.9237, 3),
       (33.4912,-111.9237, 4),
       (33.4912,-111.9237, 5),
       (38,     -97,       6)

)
SELECT
    area(circle(polygon( string_agg(one_point, ',') ))) AS area
FROM    (
    SELECT
        '(' || lat || ',' || lng || ')' AS one_point
    FROM
        points
    ORDER BY
        sort_order
    ) AS s0 ;
```

If I understand well your tables (whose definitions you can include in your question), that would be

```
SELECT
    area(circle(polygon( string_agg(one_point, ',') ))) AS area
FROM    (
    SELECT
        '(' || latdec_src || ',' || longdec_src || ')' AS one_point
    FROM
        access 
    WHERE  
        id ='99999' and time >= '2017-01-03' and time < '2017-01-04'
    ORDER BY
        time
    ) AS s0 ;
```

(I really don't know if this is going to give you an area if you just use longitude and latitude values; but that's another story.)